# Why is VS Code inserting a semicolon instead of a # when toggling line comments in Python files?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, comments

When I try to add a line comment in a Python file (using `Ctrl` + `/` ), I get `;` instead of `#`. [auto comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIDcw.png).

I have disabled the ncl extensions and checked the keyboard shortcuts, but it didn't work.
And I also check the language-configuration.json, it seems no problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ziWJ.png)
I am searching for a long time on net. But no use.

Why is this happening, and how can I change VS Code to toggle line comments with semicolons?

Comment: What extensions are you using? Is there a complete [Python expansio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) installed? Why does `MagicPython` display in the lower right corner of your picture?  What is your file type?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: also, the problem could be with keyboard layout, check this out

Comment: @JialeDu  I have installed complete python extensions, and the file type is  ``*.ipynb`` , the same problem also appears at  ``*.py`` . I use this picture because we can confirm that the language module is correct through `MagicPython` . Since  `;`  is the line comments format of NCL,  I checked again and found that I missed disabling the extension `pyNGL` . Thanks again for your comments!

Comment: I installed `pyNGL` and there was no annotation error. I guess there may be some settings that cause your machine to add an error comment.

Answer (score -1):

According to the comments above by the asker of the question, the problem was due to the [`Feliks.PyNGL`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Feliks.PyNGL) being enabled.

Whenever you have problems with behaviours that might be related to extensions, use the following procedure to determine the possible source of the problem: Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.